# Click button with spacebar

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button with an anchor, that I would like to trigger with the spacebar for accessibility reasons. Instead, clicking the spacebar jumps the page down when button is in focus.

```
<a href="stackoverflow.com">Go to Stack Overflow</a>
```

I have tried eating the spacebar key:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) { 
  return !(e.keyCode == 32);
};
```

but of course this is not what I want. I'm not sure if mapping the spacebar key to the enter key is a smart solution, or if its possible. How can I trigger a button with the spacebar using pure JS?

Comment: Just a heads-up, using `<a>` as an anchor has been deprecated in HTML5. In HTML 4.01, the `<a>` tag could be either a hyperlink or an anchor. In HTML5, the `<a>` tag is always a hyperlink, but if it has no `href` attribute, it is only a placeholder for a hyperlink.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to look into a prevent default solution:

```
window.onkeydown = function(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 32) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector('a').click(); //This will trigger a click on the first <a> element.
    }
};
```

That will stop the space bar from performing the default action (to send a space) and then you can add your scroll to command below that inside the function.

Comment: Perfect. Just changed document.querySelector('a') to document.querySelector('a.myClassName') - otherwise will target the first element in the document. For future readers! Thanks for the quick response

Comment: @fouroh4 um no it's not lol, should end with }; if i'm correct?

Answer (score 4):

Give your a link an id and try this:

```
var link = document.getElementById("link");

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        link.click();
    }
};
```

Comment: This was pretty much exactly what I needed. Just changed document.onkeydown to link.onkeydown to make sure I'm targeting the element alone. Thanks!